# Using custom UserAgent in WebView causes font to not display

Tags: android, fonts, webview, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I'm using a WebView on Android 4.3 and if I set the UserAgent to anything but null with [`WebSettings.setUserAgentString (String ua)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setUserAgentString(java.lang.String)) it causes the WebView to not load some of the fonts (used as graphics) correctly. On Android 4.4 with the new WebView from Chrome everything works pefectly.

There must be some side-effects by setting a custom UserAgent (which reaches the Server just fine).

Has anyone experienced this as well?

Comment: The null value was just to test what would happen (and it happens the same as if I wouldn't call the setUserAgentString method at all). We are in control of the server and both times the same resources (=> fonts too!) got requested and received. The WebView somehow just chooses to ignore them..

Comment: seems to be weird webview behaviour..are you facing this issue on some particular fonts or all fonts? i mean other websites are running fine or not ?